# Expresso Store - Optionally automatically register members during checkout

Tags: expresso-store

In the summary of features of Store at: https://exp-resso.com/store it states you can "Optionally automatically register members during checkout"

But I can't find the setting in the control panel or any documentation on how to set this up...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

-- EDIT --
Figured this one out ->
This is possible via the register_member parameter of the checkout form or by using a register member field in the form. Adrians answer below has full details.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable member registration, you can either use the `register_member="yes"` tag parameter, or submit a the `register_member` field (e.g. as a checkbox) in your checkout:

```
{field:register_member} <label for="register_member">Register Member Account?</label>

<!-- These fields are optional -->
<div class="toggle">
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    {field:password}
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
    {field:password_confirm}
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    {field:username}
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="screen_name">Screen Name</label>
    {field:screen_name}
  </div>
</div>
```

Complete documentation on registering members during checkout is here:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#registering_members

Comment: Should be noted specifically `register_member="yes"` (unless I was doing something wrong at the time... but personally just `register_member=""` didn't seem to work).

Comment: Can someone make a note to update the [docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#registering_members), too, then? :D

Comment: Good idea. Done :)

Comment: Store 2.1.0 documentation has the same problem again. Ambiguous suggestions for `register_member` for either `=""` or `TRUE`. It still expects `register_member="yes"` as a checkout tag parameter value, but `value="1"` if using a hidden input field directly. I was using `<input type="hidden" id="register_member" name="register_member" value="yes" />` in my HTML for Store 1.6.x, but this broke my guest -> new member checkout flow in Store 2.1.0. Would be nice if this could be mentioned in the Updates section =)

Answer (score 1):

I just found the 'register_member' parameter [in the checkout tag documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#register_member).

Comment: To expand on what Tom said - it's perfectly fine to answer your own question on Stack Exchange (as other people may have the same problem and your answer will help them), but please try to write up a detailed answer with links to help future readers, just as you would when answering any other question. Thanks :)